# Is $f: \mathbb Q^+→\mathbb Q^+$, where $f(x) =x^4$, is injective or surjective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As question title, is that function injective, surjective, bijective?

I know that:

$f: \mathbb R → \mathbb R$, where $f(x) =x^4$, is not injective, not surjective; http://www.saralstudy.com/study-eschool-ncertsolution/mathematics/relations-and-functions/1549-let-f-r-rarr-r-be-defined-as-f-x-x4-choose

$f: \mathbb R^+ → \mathbb R^+$, where $f(x) =x^4$, is bijective;

Comment: Read the definitions.

Comment: How is it not injective?

Answer (score 3):

$f$ is injective: $f(x)=f(y) \iff 0=x^4-y^4=(x - y) (x + y) (x^2 + y^2)$. But $x,y>0$ implies $(x + y) (x^2 + y^2)>0$. Therefore, $x=y$.

$f$ is not surjective: $4\in\mathbb Q^+$ is not a fourth power since $\sqrt[4]{4}=\sqrt2$ is irrational.